Unexpected working of CopyOnWriteArrayList with newScheduledThreadPool
Creating a multi-threaded program to calculate the factorial of a no using ExecutorService. Here is the code:
package org.example.executorsExample;

// example of how to use Callable and newScheduledThreadPool

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Example2 {
    static record FactRec(int num, Future<?> f) {}

    public static BigDecimal factorial(long n){
        BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE;

        while (n > 0) {
            result = result.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(n));
            n--;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<FactRec> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                Iterator<FactRec> iterator = list.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    FactRec curr = iterator.next();
                    if(curr.f.isDone()){
                        try {
                            System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
                            System.out.printf("%d! = %s%n", curr.num, curr.f.get());
                            System.out.println("------------------------------");
                            iterator.remove();   // <- if i remove this, then its working. Why?
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    } else{
                        System.out.println("Task is still running");
                    }
                }

            }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            while (true){
                System.out.print("\nEnter a num: ");
                int num = scanner.nextInt();

                if(num == 0){
                    System.out.println("Terminating ....");
                    break;
                }

                Future<BigDecimal> future = es.submit(() -> {
                    return factorial(num);
                });

                list.add(new FactRec(num, future));
            }

        } finally {
            int activeCount = ((ThreadPoolExecutor) es).getActiveCount();
            System.out.println("Active threads: " + activeCount);
            scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
            es.shutdown();
        }
    }
}

After every user input I am storing the associated Future object in CopyOnWriteArrayList, then using newScheduledThreadPool to print the result of the Future object. However, the issue is Callable passed to newScheduledThreadPool, executing only once, on second user input nothing gets printed.
Whats surprising is that if I remove iterator.remove() inside the Callable, then it works fine.
What am I missing?

The key thing to note here is that modifiying a collection while iterating over it is a very tricky process.
Looking at the Javadoc of Iterator.java for the remove method:
 /**
 * Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned
 * by this iterator (optional operation).  This method can be called
 * only once per call to {@link #next}.
 * <p>
 * The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection
 * is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by
 * calling this method, unless an overriding class has specified a
 * concurrent modification policy.
 * <p>
 * The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if this method is called
 * after a call to the {@link #forEachRemaining forEachRemaining} method.
 *
 * @implSpec
 * The default implementation throws an instance of
 * {@link UnsupportedOperationException} and performs no other action.
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the {@code remove}
 *         operation is not supported by this iterator
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the {@code next} method has not
 *         yet been called, or the {@code remove} method has already
 *         been called after the last call to the {@code next}
 *         method
 */
default void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
}

Now the question is, which iterator is in place for the CopyOnWriteArrayList? It has its own anonymous implementation that is returned from the .iterator() method, the COWIterator. Here is the code for its remove method:
     /**
     * Not supported. Always throws UnsupportedOperationException.
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException always; {@code remove}
     *         is not supported by this iterator.
     */
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

So your program should throw an UnsupportedOperationException at the iterator.remove() step. Using a debugger and setting a breakpoint, indeed it does. Why does it not pop up in the console and stop the program? That's written in the javadoc of ScheduledExecutorService:
 /**
 * Submits a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the
 * given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period;
 * that is, executions will commence after
 * {@code initialDelay}, then {@code initialDelay + period}, then
 * {@code initialDelay + 2 * period}, and so on.
 *
 * <p>The sequence of task executions continues indefinitely until
 * one of the following exceptional completions occur:
 * <ul>
 * <li>The task is {@linkplain Future#cancel explicitly cancelled}
 * via the returned future.
 * <li>The executor terminates, also resulting in task cancellation.
 * <li>An execution of the task throws an exception.  In this case
 * calling {@link Future#get() get} on the returned future will throw
 * {@link ExecutionException}, holding the exception as its cause.
 * </ul>
 * Subsequent executions are suppressed.  Subsequent calls to
 * {@link Future#isDone isDone()} on the returned future will
 * return {@code true}.
 *
 * <p>If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
 * subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
 * execute.
 *
 * @param command the task to execute
 * @param initialDelay the time to delay first execution
 * @param period the period between successive executions
 * @param unit the time unit of the initialDelay and period parameters
 * @return a ScheduledFuture representing pending completion of
 *         the series of repeated tasks.  The future's {@link
 *         Future#get() get()} method will never return normally,
 *         and will throw an exception upon task cancellation or
 *         abnormal termination of a task execution.
 * @throws RejectedExecutionException if the task cannot be
 *         scheduled for execution
 * @throws NullPointerException if command or unit is null
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if period less than or equal to zero
 */
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                              long initialDelay,
                                              long period,
                                              TimeUnit unit);

So the exception would be "trackable" by calling get on the returned ScheduledFuture.
Now, as this answers the main question, 2 more small remarks to the code you presented:

No need for static keyword for inner records.
The Scanner that you use is a Closeable. Whenever working with a Closeable and a try-block, use try-with-resources instead. Just move it one line down to the try and make it try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){ ... to ensure it is properly closed.

